# Debugging and printing in Flask

Tags: python, flask

My app seems to start fine when I dont use the debug mode, but when I turn it on with `app.run(debug= True,port=5500)`:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
[31m   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.[0m
[2m   Use a production WSGI server instead.[0m
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
```

I read in another question that installing watchdog with `pip install watchdog` may be a solution.. but (with debug mode on and watchdog installed):

```
 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
[31m   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.[0m
[2m   Use a production WSGI server instead.[0m
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with watchdog (windowsapi)
```

This is the output I get when I turn off the debug mode:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
[31m   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.[0m
[2m   Use a production WSGI server instead.[0m
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5500/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

My main problem is that I need to make prints to the console to be able to debug the development of my application. When I run the application in debug mode, it works but the console freezes as shown above. The prints do not generate an error but they are simply ignored or redirected to another place (which I do not know). I tried many options (after reading several questions in this forum):

```
print("Log?", flush=True)
app.logger.info('This is info output') (for this example I also used `import logging`)
```

I'm honestly not sure if the debug problem is related to the inability to use print in my functions. Some time ago I made an app in flask and it worked for me.
I attach my code below, from the templates and js side everything seems to work correctly.

```
from flask  import Flask, render_template, request, abort, redirect, session
from zenora import APIClient
from config import BOT_TOKEN, CLIENT_SECRET, PORT, OAUTH_URL, REDIRECT_URI
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)
client = APIClient(BOT_TOKEN, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)

app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = CLIENT_SECRET

@app.route("/")
def home():
    app.logger.info("Log?")
    print("Log?")
    access_token = session.get("access_token")
    wallet       = session.get("wallet")
    wallet = str(wallet)
    if not wallet or wallet == "None":
        return render_template("index.html",  wallet = 0, wallet_disp = 0 )
    else:
        wallet_disp = wallet[0:4] + "..." + wallet[38:]
        if(not access_token):
            return render_template("index.html", wallet=wallet, wallet_disp=wallet_disp)
        else:
            bearer_client = APIClient(access_token, bearer=True)
            current_user = bearer_client.users.get_current_user()
            return render_template("hub.html", user=current_user)


@app.route("/login")
def login():
    print("Log?")
    return redirect(OAUTH_URL)


@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session.pop("access_token")
    return redirect("/")


@app.route("/oauth/callback")
def oauth_callback():
    code = request.args["code"]
    access_token = client.oauth.get_access_token(
        code, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI
    ).access_token
    session["access_token"] = access_token

    return redirect("/")

@app.route("/wallet/callback/<wallet>")
def oauth_wallet_callback(wallet):
    session["wallet"] = wallet
    return redirect("/")

@app.route("/wallet/errase")
def oauth_wallet_errase():
    try:
        session.pop("wallet")
    except:
        pass
    return redirect("/")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5500,debug=True) 
    #app.run(port=5500)
```

The logs are now simulated with `print("Log?")` and are important to me because this app will be used to sign in in multiple accounts.. Of course they will be removed in the future.

```
async-timeout                     3.0.1
attrs                             21.2.0
certifi                           2021.10.8
cffi                              1.15.0
chardet                           4.0.0
charset-normalizer                2.0.9
click                             8.0.3
colorama                          0.4.4
cryptography                      36.0.1
cytoolz                           0.11.2
discord                           1.7.3
discord.py                        1.7.3
distlib                           0.3.4
djangorestframework-jwt           1.11.0
et-xmlfile                        1.1.0
eth-abi                           2.1.1
eth-account                       0.5.6
eth-hash                          0.3.2
eth-keyfile                       0.5.1
eth-keys                          0.3.3
eth-rlp                           0.2.1
eth-typing                        2.2.2
eth-utils                         1.10.0
filelock                          3.4.0
Flask                             2.0.2
flask-marshmallow                 0.14.0
Flask-MySQLdb                     0.2.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy                  2.5.1
greenlet                          1.1.2
h11                               0.12.0
hexbytes                          0.2.2
idna                              3.3
ipfshttpclient                    0.8.0a2
itsdangerous                      2.0.1
Jinja2                            3.0.3
jsonschema                        3.2.0
jwt                               1.3.1
lru-dict                          1.1.7
MarkupSafe                        2.0.1
marshmallow                       3.14.1
marshmallow-sqlalchemy            0.27.0
multiaddr                         0.0.9
multidict                         5.2.0
mysql                             0.0.3
mysql-connector-python            8.0.27
mysqlclient                       2.1.0
netaddr                           0.8.0
numpy                             1.21.5
openpyxl                          3.0.9
pandas                            1.3.5
parsimonious                      0.8.1
pip                               21.1.1
platformdirs                      2.4.0
protobuf                          3.19.1
pycparser                         2.21
pycryptodome                      3.12.0
PyJWT                             1.7.1
PyMySQL                           1.0.2
pyrsistent                        0.18.0
python-dateutil                   2.8.2
pytz                              2021.3
pywin32                           303
requests                          2.26.0
rlp                               2.0.1
setuptools                        56.0.0
six                               1.16.0
SQLAlchemy                        1.4.28
toolz                             0.11.2
typing-extensions                 4.0.1
urllib3                           1.26.7
uuid                              1.30
uvicorn                           0.16.0
varint                            1.0.2
virtualenv                        20.10.0
watchdog                          2.1.6
web3                              5.25.0
websockets                        9.1
Werkzeug                          2.0.2
yarl                              1.7.2
Zenora                            0.
```